# enough conditions to check that a matrix doesn't have Cholesky factorization while factorizing it

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, numerics, matrix-factorization, cholesky

I wrote this code to find Cholesky factorization of a symmetric positive definite matrix in MatLab:

```matlab
function L = cholesky(A)
    n = length(A);
    L = zeros(n, n);
    for i=1:n
        l = L_solver(L(1:i-1, 1:i-1), A(1:i-1, i));
        L(i, 1:i-1) = l;
        L(i, i) = sqrt(A(i, i) - l.'*l);
    end
end
```

Which `L_solver(L, b)` solves linear system $Lx=b$ and returns $x$. Then I tried to improve it. If the input matrix $A$ is not positive definite, it finds the least non-negative integer $t$ such if we add $tI$ to $A$, it becomes positive definite and we can return its Cholesky factorization. And we also return that $t$. This is how I modified the code:

```matlab
function [L, t] = cholesky_decomposition(A)
    n = length(A);
    t = 0;
    while true
        L = zeros(n, n);
        found = true;
        for i=1:n
            l = L_solver(L(1:i-1, 1:i-1), A(1:i-1, i));
            L(i, 1:i-1) = l;
            L(i, i) = sqrt(A(i, i) - l.'*l);
            if (imag(L(i, i)) > 0) || A(i, i) <= 0
                t = t + 1;
                A = A + eye(n, n);
                found = false;
                break;
            end
        end
        if found
            break;
        end
    end
end
```

As I searched, the most efficient method to check if a matrix is positive definite, is to check if it has Cholesky factorization. So I try to factorize it and if I reach an entry on the main diagonal that isn't positive or inside the square-root becomes negative, I add $I$ to the matrix. I want to know if these two conditions are correct and enough in this scenario.

Comment: Just a small nitpick (but a professionally important one), while enough is a decent word to describe what you want to ask, it is still vague. Mathematically precise terms are "sufficient conditions" and "necessary conditions".

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to figure out what is known as Modified Cholesky. There are a lot of resources on it, but McSweeney's thesis is a good starting point "Modified Cholesky Decomposition and Applications". This thesis builds upon a lot of prior work, particularly, "Sheung Hun Cheng and Nicholas Higham, A Modified Cholesky Algorithm Based on a Symmetric Indefinite Factorization, SIAM J. Matrix Anal. Appl. 19(4), 1097–1110, 1998."

There is a related GitHub repository with Matlab code in it: https://github.com/higham/modified-cholesky